# Sharing Data Between two Android Apps using Network Sockets

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I'm totally new to network sockets so any help is appreciated.

I'd like to know how to setup a network socket on an Android device and use it to pass data generated by an App to another App on the device.

This is because the App receiving the Data will at some point have to be able to receive data from an external source, so I'd like to build in the basics of this before I get to that point.

Any example code etc. would be great and I'll edit my question as I go if required.

Comment: you probably want to take a look at KryoNet, very nice library for sending data between apps: https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/

Comment: Ok cheers but do you know if there is any way of setting up network sockets etc. without the use of extra libraries using only the basics in the java library?

Comment: Of course there is. But then you would be re-inventing the wheel. It would be basically doing the same code in the library again. If you really want to write your own, you can start by looking on how the library is doing to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using sockets can solve your problem. Only one app can be active at a given time, and the connection won't work. Unless you create some sort of service, but this approach seems wrong.

I believe you have 2 basic options in front of you:

1. A server that both apps communicate with.
2. Writing information to the disk in a globally readable place.

The server option is better IMO.

Comment: okay thankyou, so i need to have a service running, in the background of the app collecting the information, sending information to the network socket on the device?

Comment: It might be possible, I haven't tried doing something of that sort myself. I still advise against it though. The whole idea is that apps are supposed to be **sandboxed** and disconnected from each other. You might hit a few road blocks if you try this approach.

Comment: okay its just that i need there to be something supplying the information to the App and without a second application or background service which i could remove later i dont see how i could supply this information

Comment: I don't see a reason not to create a simple web server to supply that information.

Comment: yeah ive pretty much done that now got myself a java book! :L thankyou for your help :)